# p4 diff2 also displaying changelist descriptions

Tags: perforce

I'm new to Perforce, but I need help. I am writing .bat files to do a p4 diff2 on my branches to see what changes I would need to integrate. I also have a file that will do p4 changes to show me all pending and submitted changelists.

What I want to do is perform a p4 diff2 -b [branch] >file.txt to put all the info into a txt file, but I also want it to include not just the files that need to be integrated, but the changelist descriptions that went with each one. The goal is to see WHY each file was changed.

Is there an easy way to do this?

EDIT: Also, if there is an easy way to output this info into an excel sheet or csv format, that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be you are trying to duplicate functionality already built in to Perforce. Have a look at the 'p4 interchanges' command, which will tell you what needs integrating between branches.

Just do 'p4 help interchanges' to get the docs. The -l option displays full text of changelist descriptions.